# Print header from csv file using dictReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am fairly new in Python and have just recently started studying it. I Have a problem reading the header portion of a csv file my lecturer had provided for the class.

I am trying to use dictReader function to determine the highest element number and print the Avatar with the Highest Element number. For Aang, his highest Element is 'Air' and Gyatso's is 'Water' however, i'm only able to print their highest values out. I know dictReader operates in a way that the for loop is only able to traverse the csv file row by row, skipping the header.

The .csv file:

[image: [data.csv]

My code:

```
print("{0:<12}|{1:>12}".format("Avatar Name", "Top Element"))
import csv
filePath = "data.csv"
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader  = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        element_air = 'Air'
        element_water = 'Water'
        element_earth = 'Earth'
        element_fire = 'Fire'
        for row in reader:
                 max_element = max(int(row['Air']),int(row['Water']),int(row['Earth']),int(row['Fire']))
                 if(max_element == row['Air']):
                      max_element = str(row[4])
                 if(max_element == row['Water']):
                      max_element = str(row[5])
                 if(max_element == row['Earth']):
                      max_element = str(row[6])
                 if(max_element == row['Fire']):
                      max_element = str(row[7])
        print("{0:<12}|{1:^5}".format(row['name'], max_element))
print("==============================================")
```

I tried to convert the max_element to a string but it would still print out the same result. The row[4],row[5] etc.. are the headers that I am trying to assign this max element to.

I've even tried to assign max_element == element_air.....element_fire if the max element matches the highest value so that it would print the highest value's string.

Expected result:
[image: expected]

Actual result:

[image: actual]

Comment: Within all of your if statements why not do max_element='Air', etc.  Since you're re-assigning at at each loop it should work fine.

Comment: @Chris I did a similar one as stated in my question above, just that i did max_element = element_air. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reassign `max_element` in each if-statement, just print this element out

```
elements = ('Air', 'Water', 'Fire', 'Earth')
for row in reader:
    max_element = max(row[elem] for elem in elements)
    for element in elements:
        if row[element] == max_element:
            print("{0:<12}|{1:^5}".format(row['name'], element))
            break
```

Comment: It kinda works except for an allignment issue in 'Water'. Any way to fix that?

Comment: It's because you used `:^5` in string formatting which equals to length of word "water". You can remove this alignment option (`"{0:<12}| {1} ".format(row['name'], element)`)  or increase width (`"{0:<12}|{1:^10}".format(row['name'], element)`)